# How can I create a copy of a image that carries my edits within Lightroom Classic CC?

Tags: lightroom, post-processing, photoshop, photo-editing, presets

I'm using a workflow within Lightroom Classic CC that I don't believe to be optimal. What I do sometimes to achieve the results that I want is to make some ajustments within Lightroom, fixing exposure, shadows, highligts, camera correction and etc. Then I open the image with Photoshop CC carrying the Lightroom changes and just save the image in order to generate a TIFF file, then I go back to Lightroom and work on styling, sometimes using some select presets that I like.

If I open the image and just apply the preset the results are far inferior than when using this weird and clunky method. I've tried Virtual Copies, however when using the Virtual Copy the changes aren't made on top of my previous edits, they override them.

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no way I know of to apply a preset with it not re-zeroing the adjustments, as they are all based off of a zero setting. However there is an easier way to do what you are doing without leaving lightroom.

Create an Export Preset with the following settings:

**Export Location:**

Export To: Same folder as original photo

Check "Add to This Catalog"

Set "Add to Stack" as you see fit.

**File Naming:**

Probably want to leave that so it doesn't rename it, but it will change the extension to ".TIF".

**File Settings:**

Image Format: TIFF

**Image Sizing:**

Unchecked

**Output Sharpening:**

Unchecked

**Metadata:**

All Metadata

**Watermarking:**

Unchecked

Next, Click **Add** to save this as an export preset, call it something like "Convert To TIFF"

This will export as a TIFF and then add the tiff to your catalog (import it into the same folder).

So your workflow would be:

1. Set your corrections.
2. Click export, select your "Convert to tiff" export preset, click Export.
3. After the preset exports and reimports, you simply select it and work with the presets.

Comment: This will save me a lot of time in the future! I've tried and it works just fine. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The most features of Lightroom you can use in the Raw-Filter of Photoshop. So you can apply your corrections. 
Another method would be to use the corrections layers and filters, that are equivalent to your adjustments.